# TESTNG IF statement not working with Passed Paramters from xml

Tags: testng, parameter-passing, testng-dataprovider

Research : [Selenium/Testng - IF statement not working when using parameter from testng.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11210899/selenium-testng-if-statement-not-working-when-using-parameter-from-testng-xml)
already gone through the above post , but could not find the answer.

Problem : 
Here's my TestNG.xml

```
<test name="abc">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.gunjan.automation.test.abcTesting">
            <parameter name="shareType" value="twitter, facebook"></parameter>
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>
```

Here's my snippet of Java file where I have put Test Methods

```
@Test(groups = {"web"}, dataProvider = "getData", priority = 7)
public void verifyShare(String shareType) {
    String data = shareType;
    if(data.equals("facebook"))
        System.out.println("its facebook");
    if(data.equals("twitter"))
        System.out.println("its twitter");
    System.out.println(shareType); }
```

Here's is the Data Provider method

```
@DataProvider(name = "getData")
public Object[][] getData(ITestContext context) {
    String paramter = context.getCurrentXmlTest().getClasses().get(0).getLocalParameters().get("shareType");

    String[] paramArray = paramter.split(",");
    Object[][] finalReturn = new Object[paramArray.length][1];
    for(int i = 0; i < paramArray.length; i++)
    {
        finalReturn[i][0] = paramArray[i];
    }
    return finalReturn; }
```

Since the **DataProvider** returns an array of object[], the Test method **verifyShare**, should print the following.

```
its twitter
twitter
its facebook
facebook
```

but the actual output I get is

```
its twitter
twitter
facebook
```

**its facebook** is missing.

that is, it skips the **if condition**, the **second** time it executes the test method **verifyShare**.

Also if I add three values in TestNG.xml like value = "twitter, facebook, whatsapp",
the if condition is skipped for facebook & WhatsApp values.

Any help is most appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Got it. 
The problem was silly, I wasn't using Trim(), on the Paramter.
as a result the value was " facebook" instead of "facebook".

:D :P